# How to fix the errors when installing beam on Google Colab

Tags: apache-beam, google-colaboratory

I started learning beam, and found google colab is a good place to start it (per a course I am following), however, the first thing is to install beam in Colab and it throws some error when I attempt to do it:

!{'pip3 install --quiet apache_beam'}

```
ERROR: pydrive 1.3.1 has requirement oauth2client>=4.0.0, but you'll have oauth2client 3.0.0 which is incompatible. 
ERROR: chainer 6.5.0 has requirement typing<=3.6.6, but you'll have typing 3.7.4.1 which is incompatible. 
ERROR: chainer 6.5.0 has requirement typing-extensions<=3.6.6, but you'll have typing-extensions 3.7.4.1 which is incompatible. 
ERROR: albumentations 0.1.12 has requirement imgaug<0.2.7,>=0.2.5, but you'll have imgaug 0.2.9 which is incompatible.
```

[image]

btw, python version is 3.6.9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the future reader here, the following commands work for me at the moment:

```
!pip install apache-beam[gcp]
import apache_beam as beam
```

Comment: For me although above resolved installation and beam error, it showed errors when using `beam` object later in the script. Instead, `!pip install apache-beam[interactive]` worked for me in Google Colab

Answer (score -2):

```
!pip install apache-beam[interactive]
```

It works fine for me.